# Nightmare on deciding database schema

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am in greatest nightmare on deciding a database schema ! Recently signed of my first freelancer project:

It has a user registration, and there is pretty decent requirements on user table as follows:

- name
- password
- email
- phone
- is_active
- email_verified
- phone_verified
- is_admin
- is_worker
- is_verified
- has_payment
- last_login
- created_at

Now am at huge confusion to decide whether to put everything under a single table or split things, as still i need to add few more fields like

- token
- otp ( may be in future )
- otp_limit ( may be in future ) // rate limiting

And may be something more in future when there is an update: I am afraid that, if there is an future update with new field to table then how to add that again if its a single table

And if i split things will that cause performance issue ? As most of the fields are moderately used on the webapp:

Please help me to decide, this is my first freelancing experience ( and its pretty tough and rough ) :(

Comment: No matter how you design your database, user requirements will change and your database will change.  [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) will eliminate duplicate data and perform well enough on a MySQL database.

Comment: Do i need normalization for this ?

Comment: Time to follow a published academic textbook on information modelling & DB design. Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question where 1st stuck. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

If two tables have the same `PRIMARY KEY`, they should (with few exceptions) be combined in the same table.  So, one table.

As for adding columns for future expansion, don't.  Do `ALTER TABLE .. ADD COLUMN ..` when new columns are needed.

Once you have more than a million rows, adding a column becomes invasive, so try to get most new columns added before then.

You mentioned `payment`.  If there is only one payment, simply have a column(s) with the amount and/or date.  Make them `NULLable` to indicate that it has not been paid yet.  If there will be multiple payments, then have another table dedicated to "payments", with zero or more *rows* for the payments.

That `NULL` technique won't work for a "verified" flag; it does need a separate column.

`is_worker`, `is_admin` -- Consider a single column that is an `ENUM` or `SET` to provide boolean "attributes for the user.  Use `SET` if, for example, a user can be both a worker and an admin.

Each "entity" (users, payments, etc) should be a database table.  "Relations between tables are 1:1 (which I argued against, above), 1:many (eg, `user_id` in the `Payments` table), or many:many (with an extra table with 2 ids).